# Map two arrays by index

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary, hash

I have the following arrays:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

and I would like the following output:

```
{'a' => [1, 3], 'b'=> [2], 'c' => [4]}
```

Is there a short handed way of doing this in Ruby? Currently, I am using a loop and index to create the hash.

Comment: Sorry what I meant by index is that an element at a given index in arr1 should be mapped to the element in arr2 at the same given index (i.e. a=>1, b=> 2, c=>4)

Comment: `arr2.zip(arr1).group_by(&:shift).tranform_values(&:flatten)` this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Your `arr2` contains _variables_ `a`, `b`, ..., but your desired output contains _strings_ `'a'`, `'b'`,...

Comment: I've changed `a, b, ...` to `'a', 'b', ...` based on the expected output.

Comment: _"I am using a loop and index to create the hash"_ – you might want to share your code.

Answer (score 4):

##### Assuming you meant

```rb
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = %w[a b a c] # ["a", "b", "a", "d"]
```

so your second array is an array of strings instead of variables

---

You can use [group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) and [with_index](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Enumerator/with_index) enumerators to point to your variable index and group it using the second array

```rb
arr1.group_by.with_index { |_, index| arr2[index] }
```

Comment: Excellent use of the Enumerator returned by `group_by` never even considered this. This is the cleanest and most creative answer (to the point where I even removed my comments under the post) only suggestion is `Enumerable#with_index` rather than `each_with_index`

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky , I didn't know there were those "alias methods" for enumerators, it sounds way cleaner !!!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `each_index` for `Enumerator` / `Enumerable` – it would shorten your code even more.

Comment: @saviu-u I like `with_index` becuase you can specify a "start" that `each_with_index` does not support. e.g. `arr2.each_with_index.to_a #=> [["a",0],["b",1],["a",2],["d",3]` but `arr2.each.with_index(12).to_a #=> [["a",12],["b",13],["a",14],["d",15]`

Comment: @Stefan as of 2.7 we could go with `with_index {arr2[_2]}`

Answer (score 2):

You can write the following.

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

```
arr1.zip(arr2).each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |(n,c),h|
  h[c] << n
end
  #=> {"a"=>[1, 3], "b"=>[2], "c"=>[4]}
```

Let me explain this expression by starting with a straightforward procedural approach and then go through several steps to improve the code.

---

Start by creating an empty hash that will become your desired return value:

```
h = {}
```

We can then write the following

```
(0..arr1.size - 1).each do |i|
  n = arr1[i]
  c = arr2[i]
  h[c] = [] unless h.key?(c)
  h[c] << n
end
h #=>{"a"=>[1, 3], "b"=>[2], "c"=>[4]}
```

---

It's more Ruby-like, however to iterate over corresponding pairs of values from `arr1` and `arr2`, namely, `[1, 'a']`, `[2, 'b']`, and so on. To to that we use the method [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
pairs = arr1.zip(arr2)
  #=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "a"], [4, "c"]]
```

then

```
h = {}
pairs.each do |pair| 
  n = pair.first
  c = pair.last
  h[c] = [] unless h.key?(c)
  h[c] << n
end
h #=> {"a"=>[1, 3], "b"=>[2], "c"=>[4]}
```

---

One small improvement we can make is apply [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) to `pair`:

```
h = {}
pairs.each do |n,c| 
  h[c] = [] unless h.key?(c)
  h[c] << n
end
h #=> {"a"=>[1, 3], "b"=>[2], "c"=>[4]}
```

---

The next improvement is to replace `each` with [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to avoid the need for `h = {}` at the beginning and `h` at the end:

```
pairs.each_with_object({}) do |(n,c),h| 
  h[c] = [] unless h.key?(c)
  h[c] << n
end
  #=> {"a"=>[1, 3], "b"=>[2], "c"=>[4]}
```

Notice how I have written the block variables, with `h` holding the *object* that is returned (an initially-empty hash). This is another use of array decomposition. For more on that subject, see [this](https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/) article.

---

The previous expression is fine, and reads well, but the following tweak is often seen:

```
pairs.each_with_object({}) do |(n,c),h| 
  (h[c] ||= []) << n
end
  #=> {"a"=>[1, 3], "b"=>[2], "c"=>[4]}
```

If `h` does not have a key `c`, `h[c]` returns `nil`, so `h[c] ||= []`, or `h[c] = h[c] || []`, becomes `h[c] = nil || []`, ergo `h[c] = []`, after which `h[c] << n` is executed.

---

No better or worse than the previous expression, you may see also see the code I presented at the beginning:

```
arr1.zip(arr2).each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |(n,c),h|
  h[c] << n
end
```

Here the block variable `h` is initialized to an empty hash defined

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

This employs the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block and no argument. When a hash `h` is defined in this way, if `h` does not have a key `c`, executing `h[c]` causes `h[c] = []` to be executed before `h[c] << n` is executed.

Comment: Thorough as always but I think you will really appreciate the elegance of the competing post.

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks for the heads-up.